# Retrieving getter values with dart:mirrors reflection

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

I have the following code (simplified), that uses reflection to iterate a class's fields and getters and output the values.  The `ContainsGetter` class contains a getter, and the `ContainsField` class contains a simple field.

Using `dart:mirrors` library, I can get the value of the field by using `instanceMirror.getField(fieldName)`), but not the getter by using `instanceMirror.invoke(fieldName,[])`.

The following Dart script (using the build 17463) gives the output below:

**app script**

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors';

class ContainsGetter { // raises an error
  String get aGetter => "I am a getter";
}

class ContainsField { // works fine
  String aField = "I am a field";
}

void main() {
  printFieldValues(reflect(new ContainsField()));
  printGetterValues(reflect(new ContainsGetter()));
}

void printFieldValues(instanceMirror) {
  var classMirror = instanceMirror.type;
  classMirror.variables.keys.forEach((key) {
    var futureField = instanceMirror.getField(key); // <-- works ok
    futureField.then((imField) => print("Field: $key=${imField.reflectee}"));
  });
}

void printGetterValues(instanceMirror) {
  var classMirror = instanceMirror.type;
  classMirror.getters.keys.forEach((key) {
    var futureValue = instanceMirror.invoke(key,[]); // <-- fails
    futureValue.then((imValue) => print("Field: $key=${imValue.reflectee}"));
  });
}
```

**output**

```
Field: aField=I am a field
Uncaught Error: Compile-time error during mirrored execution: <Dart_Invoke: did not find instance method 'ContainsGetter.aGetter'.>
Stack Trace:
#0      _LocalObjectMirrorImpl._invoke (dart:mirrors-patch:163:3)
#1      _LocalObjectMirrorImpl.invoke (dart:mirrors-patch:125:33)
```

(An acceptable could be that "this bit just hasn't been written yet!")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aah, I've just worked it out.  Although  `aGetter` is like a method in its implementation, you use the `getField()` rather than `invoke` to retrieve its value.

```dart
void printGetterValues(instanceMirror) {
  var classMirror = instanceMirror.type;
  classMirror.getters.keys.forEach((key) {
    var futureValue = instanceMirror.getField(key); // <-- now works ok
    futureValue.then((imValue) => print("Field: $key=${imValue.reflectee}"));
  });
}
```

Comment: Actually, it's more like that field definitions always generate getters and setters, at least on the language semantics level (not sure about implementations), so getField/setField always invokes getters/setters :-)

Comment: @Ladicek - cool thanks.  My feeling is that the mirror `getField()` function is misleading - Surely I should always be able to `invoke(getter)` or `invoke(field)` and get a value back (or `invoke(field, [value])` and invoke the setter).  Why is there a distinction between `getField` and `invoke` if behind the scenes it's effectively doing the same thing?

Comment: No idea. But it kinda reflects the syntax -- invoking methods and accessing fields (= invoking getters/setters) looks different too.